What happens to ARP replies if a switch connects to a router directly over one interface and indirectly over another?
Very typical topology:
R1 --- R2
|   X   |
SW1 - SW2
|       |
H1     H2

(The X represents SW1 connecting to R2 and SW2 to R1)
Switches 1 and 2 both connect to R1 and R2 (e.g. for FHRP).
When H1 sends an ARP request to R1, the ARP request gets to SW1.
The first time around, SW1 doesn't know R1's MAC address so its floods the request both towards R1 and towards SW2 which itself floods it back towards R1.
R1 therefore receives ARP requests both from SW1 and from SW2 and replies to both.
The ARP reply going over the fastest path will get overridden by the ARP reply going over the slowest one.
So going forward, all traffic from SW1 to R1 will go over the slowest path.
Am I missing something? I suppose STP might solve this, but what if there isn't STP?

ARP requests are broadcast and broadcast are forwarded by any switch (to all ports but the ingress one). How many switches you may have chained doesn't matter.
The way you connect each router to both switches means that each router needs a separate L3 "routed" port for each switch with a separate IP address. If you e.g. connect R1.1 and R2.1 to SW1, and connect R1.2 and R2.2 to SW2, then any traffic from H1 to R1.2 will run H1->SW1->SW2->R1.2.
If R1 uses R1.1 and R1.2 in a redundant fashion (active/passive) with a shared/virtual IP address, then the traffic goes to the active interface as it's the only one responding to ARP.

so it floods the request both towards R1 and towards SW2 which itself floods it back towards R1

SW1 and SW2 flood an unknown destination MAC to both R1 interfaces (and everywhere else). However, only one interface is bound or active for the requested IP address and only that one replies.
In practice, most interfaces linking up originate some kind of traffic for the switches to learn their MAC address, so flooding as you describe is not likely. E.g. an ARP probe for duplicate address detection updates all switches.

R1 therefore receives ARP requests both from SW1 and from SW2

Yes...

and replies to both.

and no, not even with a redundant setup. When the active interface is up, the passive one may receive but doesn't send anything.

So going forward, all traffic from SW1 to R1 will go over the slowest path.

That is quite possible. A redundant setup might not be optimal. However, if all link speeds are equal, there's no 'slower' path, just one with a slightly higher latency.
STP only resolves redundant/meshed bridged links. There are none in your example.

Thanks a lot. That makes sense. However what happens if H1 pings R1's loopback interface? In that case, wouldn't both R1.1 and R1.2 interfaces reply to the ARP request?

Since R1's loopback interface isn't part of H1's local subnet, H1 would use whatever gateway indicated by its local routing table - usually it'd use the default gateway. It wouldn't ARP the non-local destination but the gateway's IP.

Ah, fair. Thanks for the clarification
